# Custom Message Box code fails without out warning in latest version of Excel on Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been using this Custom Message Box Buttons class with excel for a few years now. When the code was run today it just crashed Excel no warning or message. This code was fully working when running Windows 7 and our company decided to move everyone to windows 10 without warning today... The original developer said on the site that he updated it for 64 bit so I am assuming it is something to do with windows 10.

The original website is down but you can still access the content and code using the way back machine
http://web.archive.org/web/20190304185310/http://shutupdean.com/blog/2014/08/01/vba-msgbox-custom-button-text/

The example workbook can be downloaded as well for convenience i have added the link to that as well
http://web.archive.org/web/20190317215921if_/http://shutupdean.com:80/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/CustomMsgbox.xlsm

Module Code:
modMsgbox

```
Option Explicit

Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5

Private Const IDOK = 1
Private Const IDCANCEL = 2
Private Const IDABORT = 3
Private Const IDRETRY = 4
Private Const IDIGNORE = 5
Private Const IDYES = 6
Private Const IDNO = 7

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (lpvDest As Any, lpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetProp Lib "user32" Alias "GetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function RemoveProp Lib "user32" Alias "RemovePropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetDlgItemText Lib "user32" Alias "SetDlgItemTextA" (ByVal hDlg As LongPtr, ByVal nIDDlgItem As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (lpvDest As Any, lpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
    Private Declare Function GetProp Lib "user32" Alias "GetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function RemoveProp Lib "user32" Alias "RemovePropA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetDlgItemText Lib "user32" Alias "SetDlgItemTextA" (ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
#End If

Private m_hWnd As Long

Public Property Get hWndApplication() As Long
    If m_hWnd = 0 Then
        If Application.Name = "Microsoft Access" Then
             m_hWnd = FindWindow("OMain", vbNullString)
        ElseIf Application.Name = "Microsoft Word" Then
            m_hWnd = FindWindow("OpusApp", vbNullString)
        ElseIf Application.Name = "Microsoft Excel" Then
            m_hWnd = FindWindow("XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        End If
    End If
    hWndApplication = m_hWnd
End Property


Public Function MsgBoxHookProc(ByVal uMsg As Long, _
                                ByVal wParam As Long, _
                                ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

    #If Win64 Then
        Dim lPtr As LongPtr
        Dim lProcHook As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lPtr As Long
        Dim lProcHook As Long
    #End If

    Dim cM As clsMsgbox

    Select Case uMsg
        Case HCBT_ACTIVATE
            lPtr = GetProp(hWndApplication, "ObjPtr")
            If (lPtr <> 0) Then
                Set cM = ObjectFromPtr(lPtr)
                If Not cM Is Nothing Then
                    If Len(cM.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(cM.ButtonText2) > 0 And Len(cM.ButtonText3) > 0 Then
                        If cM.UseCancel Then
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDYES, cM.ButtonText1
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDNO, cM.ButtonText2
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDCANCEL, cM.ButtonText3
                        Else
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDABORT, cM.ButtonText1
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDRETRY, cM.ButtonText2
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDIGNORE, cM.ButtonText3
                        End If

                    ElseIf Len(cM.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(cM.ButtonText2) Then
                        If cM.UseCancel Then
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDOK, cM.ButtonText1
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDCANCEL, cM.ButtonText2
                        Else
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDYES, cM.ButtonText1
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDNO, cM.ButtonText2
                        End If
                    Else
                        SetDlgItemText wParam, IDOK, cM.ButtonText1
                    End If
                    lProcHook = cM.ProcHook
                End If
            End If
            RemovePropPointer
            If lProcHook <> 0 Then UnhookWindowsHookEx lProcHook
    End Select

    MsgBoxHookProc = False
End Function
#If Win64 Then
    Private Property Get ObjectFromPtr(ByVal lPtr As LongPtr) As Object
        Dim obj As Object

        CopyMemory obj, lPtr, 4
        Set ObjectFromPtr = obj
        CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
    End Property
#Else
    Private Property Get ObjectFromPtr(ByVal lPtr As Long) As Object
        Dim obj As Object

        CopyMemory obj, lPtr, 4
        Set ObjectFromPtr = obj
        CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
    End Property
#End If
Public Sub RemovePropPointer()
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim lPtr As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lPtr As Long
    #End If

    lPtr = GetProp(hWndApplication, "ObjPtr")
    If lPtr <> 0 Then RemoveProp hWndApplication, "ObjPtr"
End Sub
```

Class Code:
clsMsgbox

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum MessageBoxIcon
    NoIcon = 0
    Critical = &H10
    Question = &H20
    Exclamation = &H30
    Information = &H40
    DefaultButton1 = 0
    DefaultButton2 = &H100
    DefaultButton3 = &H200
End Enum

Public Enum MessageBoxReturn
    Unknown
    Button1
    Button2
    Button3
End Enum

Private Const m_sSource As String = "clsMsgbox"
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE As Long = (-6)
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const MB_TASKMODAL = &H2000&

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As LongPtr, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetProp Lib "user32" Alias "SetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal hData As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function MessageBoxA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetProp Lib "user32" Alias "SetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal hData As Long) As Long
#End If

Private m_sButtonText1 As String
Private m_sButtonText2 As String
Private m_sButtonText3 As String
Private m_sPrompt As String
Private m_sTitle As String
Private m_eIcon As MessageBoxIcon
Private m_bUseCancel As Boolean

#If Win64 Then
    Private m_hInstance As LongPtr
    Private m_hThreadID As LongPtr
    Private m_lProcHook As LongPtr
#Else
    Private m_hInstance As Long
    Private m_hThreadID As Long
    Private m_lProcHook As Long
#End If

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    #If Win64 Then
        m_hInstance = GetWindowLong(CLngPtr(hWndApplication), GWL_HINSTANCE)
    #Else
        m_hInstance = GetWindowLong(hWndApplication, GWL_HINSTANCE)
    #End If

    m_hThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId()
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    RemovePropPointer
End Sub
#If Win64 Then
    Public Property Get ProcHook() As LongPtr
        ProcHook = m_lProcHook
    End Property
#Else
    Public Property Get ProcHook() As Long
        ProcHook = m_lProcHook
    End Property
#End If
Public Property Get UseCancel() As Boolean
    UseCancel = m_bUseCancel
End Property
Public Property Let UseCancel(ByVal NewValue As Boolean)
    m_bUseCancel = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Let Prompt(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sPrompt = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get Prompt() As String
    Prompt = m_sPrompt
End Property
Public Property Let Title(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sTitle = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get Title() As String
    Title = m_sTitle
End Property
Public Property Let Icon(ByVal NewValue As MessageBoxIcon)
    m_eIcon = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get Icon() As MessageBoxIcon
    Icon = m_eIcon
End Property
Public Property Let ButtonText1(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sButtonText1 = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get ButtonText1() As String
    ButtonText1 = m_sButtonText1
End Property
Public Property Let ButtonText2(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sButtonText2 = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get ButtonText2() As String
    ButtonText2 = m_sButtonText2
End Property
Public Property Let ButtonText3(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sButtonText3 = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get ButtonText3() As String
    ButtonText3 = m_sButtonText3
End Property
Public Function MessageBox() As MessageBoxReturn
    Dim bCancel As Boolean

    #If Win64 Then
        Dim lR As LongPtr
        Dim lType As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lR As Long
        Dim lType As Long
    #End If


    If Not m_hInstance > 0 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, m_sSource, "Instance handle not found"
    If Not m_hThreadID > 0 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError + 2, m_sSource, "Thread id not found"

    If Len(Me.Title) = 0 Then Me.Title = "Microsoft Excel"
    bCancel = Me.UseCancel

    If Len(Me.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText2) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText3) > 0 Then
        lType = Me.Icon Or IIf(bCancel, vbYesNoCancel, vbAbortRetryIgnore)

    ElseIf Len(Me.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText2) Then
        lType = Me.Icon Or IIf(bCancel, vbOKCancel, vbYesNo)
    Else
        If Len(Me.ButtonText1) = 0 Then Me.ButtonText1 = "OK"
        lType = Me.Icon Or vbOKOnly
    End If

    m_lProcHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, _
                                   AddressOf MsgBoxHookProc, _
                                   m_hInstance, _
                                   m_hThreadID)


    'Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    'SetProp hWndApplication, "ObjPtr", PtrFromObject(Me)

    lR = MessageBoxA(hWndApplication, Me.Prompt, Me.Title, lType Or MB_TASKMODAL)

    If Len(Me.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText2) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText3) > 0 Then
        If lR = IIf(bCancel, vbYes, vbAbort) Then
            MessageBox = Button1
        ElseIf lR = IIf(bCancel, vbNo, vbRetry) Then
            MessageBox = Button2
        ElseIf lR = IIf(bCancel, vbCancel, vbIgnore) Then
            MessageBox = Button3
        End If
    ElseIf Len(Me.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText2) Then
        If lR = IIf(bCancel, vbOK, vbYes) Then
            MessageBox = Button1
        ElseIf lR = IIf(bCancel, vbCancel, vbNo) Then
            MessageBox = Button2
        End If
    Else
        If lR = vbOK Then
            MessageBox = Button1
        End If
    End If
End Function
Public Function MessageBoxEx(ByVal Prompt As String, _
                             Optional Icon As MessageBoxIcon, _
                             Optional ByVal Title As String, _
                             Optional ByVal ButtonText1 As String, _
                             Optional ByVal ButtonText2 As String, _
                             Optional ByVal ButtonText3 As String) As MessageBoxReturn

    Me.Prompt = Prompt
    Me.Icon = Icon
    Me.Title = Title
    Me.ButtonText1 = ButtonText1
    Me.ButtonText2 = ButtonText2
    Me.ButtonText3 = ButtonText3

    MessageBoxEx = MessageBox
End Function
#If Win64 Then
    Private Property Get PtrFromObject(ByRef obj As Object) As LongPtr
        PtrFromObject = ObjPtr(obj)
    End Property
#Else
    Private Property Get PtrFromObject(ByRef obj As Object) As Long
        PtrFromObject = ObjPtr(obj)
    End Property
#End If
```

simple code to create the message box

```
Sub UnitTest1()
    Dim cC As clsMsgbox
    Dim iR As Integer

    Set cC = New clsMsgbox
    iR = cC.MessageBoxEx("Do you want to save the changes you made to whatever?", Exclamation + DefaultButton2, , "&Save", "Do&n't Save", "&Cancel")
    If iR = Button1 Then
        Debug.Print "Button1 Clicked"
    ElseIf iR = Button2 Then
        Debug.Print "Button2 Clicked"
    ElseIf iR = Button3 Then
        Debug.Print "Button3 Clicked"
    End If
end sub
```

I placed a stop in the IDE where the application crashes in the picture it is in the class. When the line is commented out the code works but the buttons do not have their assigned custom labels.

[image]

Comment: Download link was just corrected

Comment: a) probably no one here will download a macro enabled file from a suspect source (this is why you cannot upload files on SO) and b) [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please include the necessary code to reproduce/understand your issue in the question itself (and format it as code block) or provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: When you say *"application crashes"* what does it mean? Does Excel force close? Does it show any error message or exception? • Your function declare statement is commented out, so it does not work, and if you would use it I think `hwnd` needs to be of type `LongPtr` instead of `Long`.

Comment: It just closes the application with out warning let me post the class code that should be the only code necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of the `MessageBoxA` function is wrong. For Office 64 bit it needs to be:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBox Lib "user32" Alias "MessageBoxA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As Long) As Long
```

`hwnd` needs to be `LongPtr` and `wType` needs to be `Long` and the whole function (returne value) needs to be `Long` too.

You can look them up at: https://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt

Check all your other declares too, looks like there are some others wrong too.

---

I hope I got everything and didn't oversee something. Check it out:

#### modMsgBox

```
Option Explicit

Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5

Private Const IDOK = 1
Private Const IDCANCEL = 2
Private Const IDABORT = 3
Private Const IDRETRY = 4
Private Const IDIGNORE = 5
Private Const IDYES = 6
Private Const IDNO = 7

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (lpvDest As Any, lpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As LongPtr)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetProp Lib "user32" Alias "GetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function RemoveProp Lib "user32" Alias "RemovePropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetDlgItemText Lib "user32" Alias "SetDlgItemTextA" (ByVal hDlg As LongPtr, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (lpvDest As Any, lpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)
    Private Declare Function GetProp Lib "user32" Alias "GetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function RemoveProp Lib "user32" Alias "RemovePropA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetDlgItemText Lib "user32" Alias "SetDlgItemTextA" (ByVal hDlg As Long, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long
#End If

#If Win64 Then
    Private m_hWnd As LongPtr
#Else
    Private m_hWnd As Long
#End If

#If Win64 Then
Public Property Get hWndApplication() As LongPtr
#Else
Public Property Get hWndApplication() As Long
#End If
    If m_hWnd = 0 Then
        If Application.Name = "Microsoft Access" Then
             m_hWnd = FindWindow("OMain", vbNullString)
        ElseIf Application.Name = "Microsoft Word" Then
            m_hWnd = FindWindow("OpusApp", vbNullString)
        ElseIf Application.Name = "Microsoft Excel" Then
            m_hWnd = FindWindow("XLMAIN", vbNullString)
        End If
    End If
    hWndApplication = m_hWnd
End Property

#If Win64 Then
Public Function MsgBoxHookProc(ByVal uMsg As Long, _
                                ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
                                ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
Public Function MsgBoxHookProc(ByVal uMsg As Long, _
                                ByVal wParam As Long, _
                                ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
#End If

    #If Win64 Then
        Dim lPtr As LongPtr
        Dim lProcHook As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lPtr As Long
        Dim lProcHook As Long
    #End If

    Dim cM As clsMsgbox

    Select Case uMsg
        Case HCBT_ACTIVATE
            lPtr = GetProp(hWndApplication, "ObjPtr")
            If (lPtr <> 0) Then
                Set cM = ObjectFromPtr(lPtr)
                If Not cM Is Nothing Then
                    If Len(cM.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(cM.ButtonText2) > 0 And Len(cM.ButtonText3) > 0 Then
                        If cM.UseCancel Then
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDYES, cM.ButtonText1
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDNO, cM.ButtonText2
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDCANCEL, cM.ButtonText3
                        Else
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDABORT, cM.ButtonText1
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDRETRY, cM.ButtonText2
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDIGNORE, cM.ButtonText3
                        End If

                    ElseIf Len(cM.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(cM.ButtonText2) Then
                        If cM.UseCancel Then
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDOK, cM.ButtonText1
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDCANCEL, cM.ButtonText2
                        Else
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDYES, cM.ButtonText1
                            SetDlgItemText wParam, IDNO, cM.ButtonText2
                        End If
                    Else
                        SetDlgItemText wParam, IDOK, cM.ButtonText1
                    End If
                    lProcHook = cM.ProcHook
                End If
            End If
            RemovePropPointer
            If lProcHook <> 0 Then UnhookWindowsHookEx lProcHook
    End Select

    MsgBoxHookProc = False
End Function
#If Win64 Then
    Private Property Get ObjectFromPtr(ByVal lPtr As LongPtr) As Object
        Dim obj As Object

        CopyMemory obj, lPtr, CLngPtr(4)
        Set ObjectFromPtr = obj
        CopyMemory obj, CLngPtr(0&), CLngPtr(4)
    End Property
#Else
    Private Property Get ObjectFromPtr(ByVal lPtr As Long) As Object
        Dim obj As Object

        CopyMemory obj, lPtr, 4
        Set ObjectFromPtr = obj
        CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4
    End Property
#End If
Public Sub RemovePropPointer()
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim lPtr As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lPtr As Long
    #End If

    lPtr = GetProp(hWndApplication, "ObjPtr")
    If lPtr <> 0 Then RemoveProp hWndApplication, "ObjPtr"
End Sub
```

#### clsMsgBox

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum MessageBoxIcon
    NoIcon = 0
    Critical = &H10
    Question = &H20
    Exclamation = &H30
    Information = &H40
    DefaultButton1 = 0
    DefaultButton2 = &H100
    DefaultButton3 = &H200
End Enum

Public Enum MessageBoxReturn
    Unknown
    Button1
    Button2
    Button3
End Enum

Private Const m_sSource As String = "clsMsgbox"
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE As Long = (-6)
Private Const WH_CBT As Long = 5
Private Const MB_TASKMODAL = &H2000&

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetProp Lib "user32" Alias "SetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal hData As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function MessageBoxA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetProp Lib "user32" Alias "SetPropA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal hData As Long) As Long
#End If

Private m_sButtonText1 As String
Private m_sButtonText2 As String
Private m_sButtonText3 As String
Private m_sPrompt As String
Private m_sTitle As String
Private m_eIcon As MessageBoxIcon
Private m_bUseCancel As Boolean

#If Win64 Then
    Private m_hInstance As LongPtr
    Private m_lProcHook As LongPtr
#Else
    Private m_hInstance As Long
    Private m_lProcHook As Long
#End If

Private m_hThreadID As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    #If Win64 Then
        m_hInstance = GetWindowLongPtr(hWndApplication, GWL_HINSTANCE)
    #Else
        m_hInstance = GetWindowLong(hWndApplication, GWL_HINSTANCE)
    #End If

    m_hThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId()
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    RemovePropPointer
End Sub
#If Win64 Then
    Public Property Get ProcHook() As LongPtr
        ProcHook = m_lProcHook
    End Property
#Else
    Public Property Get ProcHook() As Long
        ProcHook = m_lProcHook
    End Property
#End If
Public Property Get UseCancel() As Boolean
    UseCancel = m_bUseCancel
End Property
Public Property Let UseCancel(ByVal NewValue As Boolean)
    m_bUseCancel = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Let Prompt(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sPrompt = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get Prompt() As String
    Prompt = m_sPrompt
End Property
Public Property Let Title(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sTitle = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get Title() As String
    Title = m_sTitle
End Property
Public Property Let Icon(ByVal NewValue As MessageBoxIcon)
    m_eIcon = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get Icon() As MessageBoxIcon
    Icon = m_eIcon
End Property
Public Property Let ButtonText1(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sButtonText1 = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get ButtonText1() As String
    ButtonText1 = m_sButtonText1
End Property
Public Property Let ButtonText2(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sButtonText2 = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get ButtonText2() As String
    ButtonText2 = m_sButtonText2
End Property
Public Property Let ButtonText3(ByVal NewValue As String)
    m_sButtonText3 = NewValue
End Property
Public Property Get ButtonText3() As String
    ButtonText3 = m_sButtonText3
End Property
Public Function MessageBox() As MessageBoxReturn
    Dim bCancel As Boolean
    Dim lR As Long
    Dim lType As Long


    If Not m_hInstance > 0 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, m_sSource, "Instance handle not found"
    If Not m_hThreadID > 0 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError + 2, m_sSource, "Thread id not found"

    If Len(Me.Title) = 0 Then Me.Title = "Microsoft Excel"
    bCancel = Me.UseCancel

    If Len(Me.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText2) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText3) > 0 Then
        lType = Me.Icon Or IIf(bCancel, vbYesNoCancel, vbAbortRetryIgnore)

    ElseIf Len(Me.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText2) Then
        lType = Me.Icon Or IIf(bCancel, vbOKCancel, vbYesNo)
    Else
        If Len(Me.ButtonText1) = 0 Then Me.ButtonText1 = "OK"
        lType = Me.Icon Or vbOKOnly
    End If

    m_lProcHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, _
                                   AddressOf MsgBoxHookProc, _
                                   m_hInstance, _
                                   m_hThreadID)


    'Private Declare PtrSafe Function MessageBoxA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpText As String, ByVal lpCaption As String, ByVal wType As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    'SetProp hWndApplication, "ObjPtr", PtrFromObject(Me)

    lR = MessageBoxA(hWndApplication, Me.Prompt, Me.Title, lType Or MB_TASKMODAL)

    If Len(Me.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText2) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText3) > 0 Then
        If lR = IIf(bCancel, vbYes, vbAbort) Then
            MessageBox = Button1
        ElseIf lR = IIf(bCancel, vbNo, vbRetry) Then
            MessageBox = Button2
        ElseIf lR = IIf(bCancel, vbCancel, vbIgnore) Then
            MessageBox = Button3
        End If
    ElseIf Len(Me.ButtonText1) > 0 And Len(Me.ButtonText2) Then
        If lR = IIf(bCancel, vbOK, vbYes) Then
            MessageBox = Button1
        ElseIf lR = IIf(bCancel, vbCancel, vbNo) Then
            MessageBox = Button2
        End If
    Else
        If lR = vbOK Then
            MessageBox = Button1
        End If
    End If
End Function
Public Function MessageBoxEx(ByVal Prompt As String, _
                             Optional Icon As MessageBoxIcon, _
                             Optional ByVal Title As String, _
                             Optional ByVal ButtonText1 As String, _
                             Optional ByVal ButtonText2 As String, _
                             Optional ByVal ButtonText3 As String) As MessageBoxReturn

    Me.Prompt = Prompt
    Me.Icon = Icon
    Me.Title = Title
    Me.ButtonText1 = ButtonText1
    Me.ButtonText2 = ButtonText2
    Me.ButtonText3 = ButtonText3

    MessageBoxEx = MessageBox
End Function
#If Win64 Then
    Private Property Get PtrFromObject(ByRef obj As Object) As LongPtr
        PtrFromObject = ObjPtr(obj)
    End Property
#Else
    Private Property Get PtrFromObject(ByRef obj As Object) As Long
        PtrFromObject = ObjPtr(obj)
    End Property
#End If
```

Comment: Ill try and convert them to the correct types when I corrected the line you suggest it gives me a type mismatch so I am assuming the code is littered with issues pertaining to that

Comment: Actually yes it is full of errors. Since `Option Explicit` is used, the first error you should get is on line `m_hInstance = GetWindowLong(CLngPtr(hWndApplication), GWL_HINSTANCE)` because `hWndApplication` is not declared. Make sure you declare all variables to the correct type before using them.

Comment: I didn't write the original code as while Im decent with VBA this area is not one where I am familiar with

Comment: @MatthewLozoya The code was a bit messy, I hope I got everything right now. Check it out. You have to make sure that everywhere is the correct type. If one `LongPtr` and `Long` is mixed up it does not work. Especially in something like `CopyMemory obj, 0&, 4` the function waits for a `LongPtr` as last parameter to ensure that you need to do `CopyMemory obj, CLngPtr(0&), CLngPtr(4)`