# Custom Message Box code fails without out warning in latest version of Excel on Windows 10 64 bit: m_hInstance not collecting value

Tags: excel, vba, api

I have used the code that provided in below link by PEH.

[Custom Message Box code fails without out warning in latest version of Excel on Windows 10 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753153/custom-message-box-code-fails-without-out-warning-in-latest-version-of-excel-on/64337663?noredirect=1#comment113769092_64337663)

Program/code is ending with below line while it is getting executed.

```
If Not m_hInstance > 0 Then Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, m_sSource, "Instance handle 
not found"

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   m_hInstance = GetWindowLong(Application.hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)
   m_hThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId()
End Sub
```

with the above Private Sub Class_Initialize() variable m_hInstance value is getting assigned with 0^ (m_hInstance = 0^) then it is getting ended.

would you please help me what is going wrong with above Private Sub Class_Initialize() and m_hInstance = 0^ ?

Comment: Not an expert on this, but the MS API help suggests you should be using GetWindowLongPtr on both 32- and 64-bit. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlonga

Comment: Thank you DS_London I have tried with GetwidnowLongPtr it got worked. I am not sure how it is working as am not expert but it is working. sorry for delayed response.